# "This view has been automatically updated to fix missing relationships" - fields removed from a working view for no reason

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n, views

I have a site built on Commerce Kickstart 1 - Views 3.7.
I have a standard cart, to which I wanted to add photos of the products. It is a view that includes a relationship to *Commerce Order: Line items* and  a contextual filter by Order ID.

Now, I added a reference to the product in order to be able to access the photos.     The view works OK, all the initial elements *and* the images are there, but when i try to edit it, all the relationships are gone and I receive the "This view has been automatically updated to fix missing relationships" message. Both the relationship I added and the default relationship to line items are gone.

RELATIONSHIPS
Commerce Order: Line items
(Line Item) Commerce Line item: Product

FIELDS:
(Line Item) Commerce Line item: Display path
(Product) Field: Image (Image)
(Line Item) Commerce Line Item: Title
(Line Item) Commerce Line item: Unit price
(Line Item) Commerce Line Item: Quantity text field
(Line Item) Commerce Line item: Total
(Line Item) Commerce Line Item: Delete button

To me it looks like a bug in Views? There is a discussion of a similar issue https://drupal.org/node/1860380 (the last post is actually mine). Maybe I am wrong, though, maybe it's me who's doing something wrong?

Comment: Could well be a bug in views - but that would preclude us helping here, as bug reports need to be kept in the module issue queue. Could also be a bug in Kickstart; version 1 is unsupported by the looks of things - time to upgrade to Kickstart 2 maybe?

Comment: Well, but maybe the someone had similar problems? And CK 1 seeems still supported - new versions appear. I like it more then CK2 because it's closer to plain Drupal.

Comment: Whether or not someone's had the same problem is irrelevant to whether the question is on topic _on this site_. Bug reports for contributed modules are always off-topic here. Fragmenting support for contrib modules over here would be disastrous for all concerned. If you haven't changed anything in the code, haven't changed anything manually in the database, and nothing else changed, then you've found a bug in a module, or at least an incompatibility between some modules you have installed. I'm afraid this isn't the right place to get help with that, you need to take it to the issue queues.

Comment: To help with your debugging: you need to narrow down which of the modules you have installed is causing the problem. Start a blank install of Drupal, adding one module at a time, and see if you can reproduce the problem. Keeping adding modules until you've re-built your site up. At that point you'll either know what module is broken, or it'll work, and you'll know it was a configuration issue first time round.

Comment: @Clive      1) Well, at the bug report (the link I posted above)  merlinofchaos suggested that it's not a bug (though I think he was wrong).
2) The bug report is in a debate whether it's a bug or not, with very little actual data included. I put  the info that I could think of there, and I am asking for advice here. If I get any help I will surely include it in the bug report. Maybe it's not a bug, maybe there's just something  I do not see/understand  about Drupal & Views.

Comment: @Clive      Thank you for debugging tips. I did test whether it's maybe a php 5.4 ot Internationalization problem - tried to run it on php 5.3 server and witout i18n module. Nothing changed.

Comment: I'm sure he's been wrong in the past (maybe even a couple of times!), but the merlin knows what he's talking about. If he says it's not a bug in views, there's a very good chance it's not a bug in views :) The way you describe it it sounds like a bug, but it's difficult (read: impossible) to debug where that's coming from without having full access to the site and its codebase. I think your best bet is either a deep-and-dark debugging session, or hope that someone comes along whose had the same problem and knows how to solve it :/

Comment: Yes, a debugging night in view (Views?). Moving stuff around from a place my grandmother used to live, i found a bottle of brandy from Yougoslavia (!), year 1971 (!). It will keep me company on that one (with moderation, of course)!

Comment: Sounds like fun ;) If you do manage to get it solved it'd be great if you could add an answer in, I'm sure it would help some poor soul in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It turned out after all that this behaviour was related to the "Administration Language" module https://drupal.org/project/admin_language‎.
Disabling it made the problem disappear for good.
It seems as its is related to access permissions.
A similar problem was encountered in creating product views in drupal commerce. If you want to relate to the fields of the referenced product, you have to grant the *View* permisssion to all *products* (non-node enitities of DC). Otherwise the users without permission to view the product enitities will see an empty view (see [Views results empty for unprivileged user when using Relationship: Content: Referenced Product](https://drupal.org/node/1276450)). What makes it especially difficult to track that the problem does show up only when one uses Relationship & "Fields" display. A similar view with content / teaser etc renders the same content without problems.

Now, I wanted to add an image of the product to the cart view. I referenced the *Image* field of the product in the cart (*(Line Item) Commerce Line item: Product*), and put the image field from there.

I understand that the permissions problem prevent the view from functioning properly. It seems to be that it's a bug that
a) the view itself functions well
b) that the problem appears in the Views UI
c) that the error message is not informative.

It seems to me that this behavior is just a side effect of a number factors in how the Views work.