# View add a new field it can't find the fields "All disappeared "

Tags: entities, nodes, views

Something strange happened to my website and suddenly all the fields disappeared from view.

I tried to create new view with content type building. the building content type has the following fields Title, photos,address,building ready,price,description and logo.

at the time of creating the view I can find all the above fields and can add them without any problem  but after few minutes the fields disappears from view and going back to add field only few common fields are available

Going back to view i can see a message "This view has been automatically updated to fix missing relationships. While this View should continue to work, you should verify that the automatic updates are correct and save this view."

[image]

[image]

During creating the view all the field are available

[image]

creating new view configuration screen

[image]

I tried to update Drupal noting changed

I tired to update Views noting changed

I tired Registry Rebuild noting changed

Comment: Have you installed any node access or field access modules of any kind? (i.e. Domain Access, Content Access, etc.)

Comment: try go to views advanced settings and disable the views data caching

Comment: @webkenny Thanks for the answer, Yes I do have content access module installed. however i am not using content access model for building content type and all the field is set to "Public (author and administrators can edit, everyone can view)"

Comment: @harsh I am not caching anything and the cache option is already none.

Comment: Would you mind taking a screenshot of your view and editing your post with it? (e.g. The actual configuration screen, not just the fields)

Comment: @Yama Have you looked at these posts: [post 1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1860380), [post 2](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84468/this-view-has-been-automatically-updated-to-fix-missing-relationships-fields), [post 3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158975).

Comment: @J.Reynolds Thanks for the help finally i manage to fix the problem by enabling master view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two nights I finally manage to make it work for me by Always show the master display from /admin/structure/views/settings and enabling.

However this is a major bug in view and to be honest pain in the bottom !

Hope next release of view will consider looking into this bug.